# Displaying average value in total column using PivotTable.js

Tags: jquery, pivottable.js

I am using pivotable.js library, in this pivotable.js I want show **average values of all cells in the total column** instead of total of all cell values. Please have a look at the image below, which show how I want to display values in in pivottable.js

[image]

```
var average = $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates.average;
var numberFormat = $.pivotUtilities.numberFormat;
var intFormat = numberFormat({digitsAfterDecimal: 1});

$("#output").pivot(
  [
    {color: "green", shape: "null", value: 0},
    {color: "blue", shape: "circle", value: 1},
    {color: "red", shape: "triangle", value: 2},
    {color: "red", shape: "triangle", value: 12},
    {color: "blue", shape: "circle", value: 3},
    {color: "blue", shape: "triangle", value: 12}
  ],
  {
    rows: ["color"],
    cols: ["shape"],
    aggregator: average(intFormat)(["value"])
  }
);
```

Could you please let me know how can I achieve this. Here is fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dky0hh1y/5/

My custom aggregator

```
 var successRate = function() {
  return function() {
    return {
      sumSuccesses: 0,
      sumTrials: 0,
      push: function(record) {
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(record.student))) {
          this.sumSuccesses += parseFloat(record.student);
        }

      },
      value: function() { return this.sumSuccesses },
      format: function(x) { return x; },
      numInputs: 0
    };
  };
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PivoTable.js uses the same aggregator function for all cells, total or not. If you want to have a different method of computing values in the total row/col you'll need to write your own custom aggregator. Here is the documentation for this https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Aggregators

Comment: I using custom aggregator only, please look at the edited question. From the custom aggregator function how can I find out Total col or row, so that I can apply different logic for total calculation

Answer (score 0):

PivoTable.js seems to apply the same calculation method to all cells, including both row and column totals. If you need custom calculation totals, allow PivoTable.js to generate the pivot after the `pvtTable` element is ready. Then, iterate through all rows and cells as shown below to generate the desired total values:

```
// Set the output tag visibility to hidden in the HTML body.
//<div id="output" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
$(document).ready(function () {
          const jsonData = getjsonData();
          $("#output").pivotUI(jsonData, { // pivotUI configuration...
   
           });


function formatTotalValue(aTotalValue, aCount) {
    // If there is no other calculation needed, simply return aTotalValue.
    return aTotalValue;

    // For calculating the average value.
    // Uncomment the next line if you want to enable this calculation.
    // return aTotalValue / aCount;
  }

  
$(".pvtTable").ready(function () {
    document.querySelector("th[class='pvtTotalLabel pvtColTotalLabel']").innerText = "Column Total Label";
    document.querySelector("th[class='pvtTotalLabel pvtRowTotalLabel']").innerText = "Row Total Label";
    var pvtTable = document.querySelector("table[class='pvtTable']");

    var firstDataRowIndex = 2; // Ignoring column names
    var totalRowindex = pvtTable.rows.length - 1;

    var firstDataCellIndex = 1; // Ignoring row names
    var totalCellindex = pvtTable.rows[totalRowindex].cells.length - 1;

    // Initialize column total values
    for (var i = firstDataRowIndex; i <= totalRowindex; i++)
        pvtTable.rows[i].cells[totalCellindex].innerText = "";

    // Initialize row total values
    for (var j = firstDataCellIndex; j < totalCellindex; j++)
        pvtTable.rows[totalRowindex].cells[j].innerText = "";

    // Calculate all total values
    for (var i = firstDataRowIndex; i < totalRowindex; i++) {
        for (var j = firstDataCellIndex; j < totalCellindex; j++) {
            cellValue = pvtTable.rows[i].cells[j].innerText;
            pvtTable.rows[i].cells[totalCellindex].innerText += cellValue;
            pvtTable.rows[totalRowindex].cells[j].innerText += cellValue;
            pvtTable.rows[totalRowindex].cells[totalCellindex].innerText += cellValue;
        }
    }

    // Format the calculated total values
    for (var i = firstDataRowIndex; i < totalRowindex; i++)
        pvtTable.rows[i].cells[totalCellindex].innerText = FormatTotalValue(pvtTable.rows[i].cells[totalCellindex].innerText, totalCellindex - firstDataCellIndex);

    for (var j = firstDataCellIndex; j < totalCellindex; j++)
        pvtTable.rows[totalRowindex].cells[j].innerText = FormatTotalValue(pvtTable.rows[totalRowindex].cells[j].innerText, totalRowindex - firstDataRowIndex);

    pvtTable.rows[totalRowindex].cells[totalCellindex].innerText = FormatTotalValue(pvtTable.rows[totalRowindex].cells[totalCellindex].innerText, (totalRowindex - firstDataRowIndex) * (totalCellindex - firstDataCellIndex));
    // ***

    // After all calculation is done, set output tag visibility = visible
    $("#output").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```